# The holonomy groupoid of certain one dimensional foliations of 2 dimensional Euclidean regions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds, noncommutative-geometry, groupoids

What Is the first  fundamental group of each of the following  $3$ dimensional Hausdorff manifolds? What  about homology groups of these 3-manifolds? Is the first one a contractible  manifold?

The  holonomy  groupoid of the  following  foliations

1)The  foliation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$  defined by  solution curves of the  differential  equation $\dot z=e^z$

2)The  foliation of $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus \{0\}$  defined  by the  Vander pol equation $$\begin{cases} \dot x=y-(x^{3}-x)\\
\dot y=-x  \end{cases}$$

The  holonomy  groupoid of  a  foliated manifold is  defined in page 123 of the  book 
[Non commutative  geometry by  Alain Connes]